# How to bundle library without npm dependencies using webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependency-management, webpack

The scenario is that I'm developing a component for use by a website and want to combine the files that I've created into one `index.js` for ease of use.

File `index.jsx` includes the line `var header = require('./header.jsx');` and `header.jsx` includes the line `var React = require('react');` where `React` has been added as an npm module.

If I use `webpack --module-bind jsx --entry .\src\index.jsx --output-file .\dist\index.js` on the command line this produces a large file with `React` source included.

Is there a way that I can have just my `index.jsx` and `header.jsx` transformed and concatenated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mark React as [an external](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals) to achieve that. Ie.

```
externals: {
    react: 'react',
}
```

Comment: This is correct for a single dependency. For multiple dependencies I used `var fs = require('fs'), node_modules = fs.readdirSync('node_modules'); module.exports = { externals: node_modules };`